# Forwarding all batch file parameters to inner command

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

For my comfort in Windows, I want to prepare some PHP tools launched like in Unix.

f.e.: `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/`

Not: `php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/`

I made **composer.bat** file in system path dir:

```
php C:\path\to\composer\composer.phar
```

and its works in simply usage.
But how to forward all parameter and flags to command inside?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

in your batch file *composer.bat*, simply put:

```
php C:\path\to\composer\composer.phar %*
```

Comment: This fails for `composer.bat "^^"` and swallows all the carets!

Comment: That's not the case on my machine with a default command prompt. The carets get passed on to the next script.

Comment: You're right - the problem only arises when invoked via `execv` or similar

Comment: @Eric So this is probably more an issue of properly [escaping the arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) than what this original question is about (and a downvote seems a little harsh...). But I just saw that someone pointed this already out in your question.

Answer (score 22):

windows gives you `%*` to refer to all parameters.

Your new **composer.bat** file will then become
`php C:\path\to\composer\composer.phar %*`

Comment: I just put that together, combining a Windows NT command script (a .CMD file) with a standard desktop shortcut that has its working directory (start in) property set to the name of the project root directory. This is a real PITA for a "dynamic" scripting language, but I have a tolerable solution.